# Regex to get all possible repeated substrings

Tags: python, regex

I need to find from "aaaa" -> 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaaa'.

I tried `re.findall(r'(.)\1{1,}')`, but all I find is 'a'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a regular expression but I think a nested list comprehension like this should do the trick. You can change `MIN_LENGTH` and `MAX_LENGTH` if you want different length substrings.

```py
test_str = "aaaa"
MIN_LENGTH, MAX_LENGTH = 2, len(test_str)

substrings = [test_str[i:i + length] for length in range(MIN_LENGTH, MAX_LENGTH +  1)
                                     for i in range(len(test_str) - length + 1)]
print(substrings)
```