# Format braces within regex count specifier braces

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

> I need to find from "aaaa" -> 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaaa'.
>
> I tried `re.findall(r'(.)\1{1,}')`, but all I find is 'a'.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74870518/python-regex-get-all-possible-repeated-substrings), I attempted to form a regex to get the desired results. However, there are `format` braces within the regex count specifier braces.

I think I've seen how that is handled but can't find it.

```
for n in range(1, 3):
    for m in re.finditer(r'(?=((.)\2{{0}}))'.format(n), 'aaaa'):
        print(m.group(1))
```

This gives:

```
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
```

but I want:

```
aa
aa
aa
aaa
aaa
```

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer rather than editing it into your question. That way the site will know your question has been answered and people can vote on the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-do-i-print-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-while-using-format/5466478#5466478). Just had to double up the braces for the regex count specifier.

```
>>> for n in range(1, 3):
    for m in re.finditer(rf'(?=((.)\2{{{n}}}))', 'aaaa'):
        print(m.group(1))

        
aa
aa
aa
aaa
aaa
>>>
```